# Deploying in android

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I have developped a worklight application (worklight 7.1 sdk) with adapter authentication. I have added an android environment. After building the android app I copied the apk to my development tablet and run it. I'm now facing 2 issues:
1) I can see that at startup time worklight queries cordova api in order to get the remote server url "cordova.exec(defaultServerQueryCallBack, defaultServerQueryCallBack, 'WLApp', 'readUserPref', [ "WLDefaultServerURL" ]);". I have noticed that the result of this query is my current development server: "http://mylabtopname:10080/MyWorklightApp". How can I set this setting in order to point to the production server?

2)I have observed that prior to invoke an adapter, worklight is invoking a cordova plugin (WLAuthorizationManagerPlugin.getClientInstanceIdHeader). Not sure what this plugin serves for but I'm getting 500 error ("Unexpected errorCode occurred. Please try again."). At android config.xml file I've seen several plugins registered (many of them are common apache cordova plugins, org.apache.cordova.xxx and many of them seem to be worklight custom plugins, com.worklight.androidgap). One of these plugins is "WLAuthorizationManagerPlugin". Debuggin with chrome/inspect I can see the folder worklight/plugins with all the "org.apache.cordova.xxx" plugins loaded, can't see any "com.worklight.androidgap.xxx", don't know if this is an issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For issue (1) you need to select run as -> bulid settings and deploy target. There you enter your remote server URL.

Read more in the documentation: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_building_and_deploying_build_settings_deploy_target.html

Comment: Thanks. It works fine for the fisrt issue. I'll open a new question for the second issue